# Is $x^3+x^2+x+1$ divisible by $x^3+5x^2+x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5\left[x\right]$?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

(for simplicity, denote $a(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1$ and $b(x)=x^3+5x^2+x$)

My assignment asks to show that $b(x)$ does not divide $a(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}\left[x\right]$, but rather that it *does* divide it in $\mathbb{Z}_5\left[x\right]$.

Long division shows that the first is obviously true, $\frac {a(x)} {b(x)}$ leaves a remainder of $r(x)=1-4x$.

But so far, I'm drawing a blank on the second. Whenever I try to use long division in this new polynomial field, I get a nonzero remainder of $r(x)=x^2+1$. (which is the remainder of the first division, with coefficients made modulo 5)

Since we're now in $\mathbb{Z}_5\left[x\right]$, $b(x)=x^3+x$ (since $5=0$) So this is true if we're using the division algorithm:

$$x^3+x^2+x+1=(1)(x^3+x)+(x^2+1)=x^3+x^2+x+1$$

Where am I having a memory leak?

Comment: Both polynomials have the same degree, so the only way for one of them to be a multiple of the other, is if they differ (multiplicatively) by a unit, i.e., by a non-zero element of ${\mathbb Z}_5$. They don't, because your $a(x)$ has terms of degree 2 and 0 and your $b(x)$ doesn't. This is essentially your argument as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you had a leak, but:

$$x^3+x^2+x+1=(x+1)(x^2+1)$$

and this much is true in the integers $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , so it is also true in $\;\Bbb Z_5\;$ . It comes from noticing that $\;-1=4\pmod5\;$ is a root of the leftmost polynomial. Observe further that since $\;5=1\pmod4\;,\;\;-1\;$ is a square in this last field, so in fact

$$x^2+1=(x-2)(x+2)\pmod5= (x+3)(x+2)\pmod5$$

so in the end

$$x^3+x^2+x+1=(x+1)(x^2+1)=(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\pmod5$$

Comment: This shows that the remainder polynomial is a multiple of $a(x)$ -- does this mean that $a(x)$ *is* divisible by $b(x)$?

Comment: If you mean $\;b(x)=a(x)q(x)+r(x)\;$ and $\;r\;$ is a multiple of $\;a\;$ , then the obvious answer is yes (the other way around as you wrote: $\;b\;$ is divisible by $\;a\;$ ) since then $\;b=aq+r=aq+r'a=a(q+r')$

Comment: I wrote b divides a, not b is divisible by a.

Comment: @jaska You're right, I changed the notation without paying attention.

Comment: There's something wrong typographically in the second displayed equation.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thank you very much, correcting now.